# How do I bring the new string to the front?

Tags: javascript, css

I've used getElementsByClassName to change the button text when people click on it, but with the JavaScript String Rule, it will not change the original text but return a new string instead.

The original text of the button is in the span tag, and I use CSS to make it visible by color and z-index. The problem is when the new string replace the original one, it will not be in the span tag which causes it to be hidden under the animation div.

If you don't understand what I mean, please check the code below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = "Copied";
  setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = "Changing Back"; }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.Big {
  width: 257px;
  padding: 33px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.ButtonMain {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

.ButtonMain::before,
.ButtonMain::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ButtonMain span {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.ButtonMain:hover span {
  color: #000;
  transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.BlueRevealEffect::before {
  content: '';
  background: #3a86ff;
  width: 120%;
  left: -10%;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.8, 1);
}

.BlueRevealEffect:hover::before {
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button
  class="demo ButtonMain BlueRevealEffect Big"
  onclick="myFunction()">
  <span>Find Out More</span>
</button>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".demo span").innerHTML = "Copied"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the desired `<span>`

```js
document.querySelector(".demo span").innerHTML
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector(".demo span").innerHTML = "Copied";
  setTimeout(function(){ document.querySelector(".demo span").innerHTML = "Changing Back"; }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.Big {
  width: 257px;
  padding: 33px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.ButtonMain {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

.ButtonMain::before,
.ButtonMain::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ButtonMain span {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.ButtonMain:hover span {
  color: #000;
  transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.BlueRevealEffect::before {
  content: '';
  background: #3a86ff;
  width: 120%;
  left: -10%;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.8, 1);
}

.BlueRevealEffect:hover::before {
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button
  class="demo ButtonMain BlueRevealEffect Big"
  onclick="myFunction()">
  <span>Find Out More</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `span` inside of button, so you need to add it when you're changing html:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = "<span>Copied</span>";
  setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = "<span>Changing Back</span>"; }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.Big {
  width: 257px;
  padding: 33px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.ButtonMain {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

.ButtonMain::before,
.ButtonMain::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ButtonMain span {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.ButtonMain:hover span {
  color: #000;
  transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.BlueRevealEffect::before {
  content: '';
  background: #3a86ff;
  width: 120%;
  left: -10%;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.8, 1);
}

.BlueRevealEffect:hover::before {
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button
  class="demo ButtonMain BlueRevealEffect Big"
  onclick="myFunction()">
  <span>Find Out More</span>
</button>
```